# Yii - FullCalendar - How set TimeZone?

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Is it possible to set the time zone?  I'd like to allow my users to select the timezone they'd like to view the calendar.  Right now, the event times ONLY change if I change the system time on my laptop computer.  I'm using version 1.5.3 and saw this in the documentation:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: {
        url: 'http://www.google.com/your_feed_url/',
        className: 'gcal-event',           // an option!
        currentTimezone: 'America/Chicago' // an option!
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

I've tried setting currentTimezone and the times don't change.  I've also searched through the included javascript files and can't any references of 'currentTimezone'.  How is this possible in versions 1.5+?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `ignoreTimezone` to **`false`**.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: {
        url: 'http://www.google.com/your_feed_url/',
        className: 'gcal-event',           // an option!
        currentTimezone: 'America/Chicago' // an option!
    },
    ignoreTimezone: false 
  });
});
</script>
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Still the same time, no changes, does this ONLY work with a google calendar?  The event time still only changes when I change my system time.

Comment: It depends on the UTC offset for that time. Check the documentation for this setting - http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/ignoreTimezone/

Comment: I've read the documentation about the ignoreTimezone setting, but regardless of how I've tried to implement the setting, the events are always displayed with respect to my system time.  Do I need to convert all of the dates from UTC timestamps to ISO8601s for this setting to take effect?